# Why doesn't git checkout FILE reapply uncommitted changes?

Tags: git

`git checkout COMMIT` switches your current state to that pointed by `COMMIT` and reapplies any uncommitted changes (it even fails nicely if your uncommitted changes are incompatible with the `COMMIT` you want to switch to.

This functions in stark contrast to `git checkout COMMIT FILE` which just blindly discards any uncommitted changes (without any warning) of `FILE` and "forces" the state of `FILE` to that in `COMMIT`.

My question is, why the inconsistency? (perhaps with regards to historic / design decisions)

Surely it could have been made such that `git checkout COMMIT FILE` attempted to reapply uncommitted changes to `FILE` and failed gracefully if that failed.  Especially since `git checkout` is often marketed as a "safe" operation.  If anything, the current behavior of `git checkout COMMIT FILE` should be the behavior of `git reset --hard COMMIT FILE`.  (On a side note, the behavior of `git reset COMMIT` and `git reset FILE` also leaves room for improvement in consistency...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `git checkout commit` switches your current state to that pointed by *`commit`* ...

Yes, sort of.  It's actually substantially more complicated under the hood.

> ... and reapplies any uncommitted changes (it even fails nicely if your uncommitted changes are incompatible with the *`commit`* you want to switch to).

It really doesn't do that first part (but does do the second), and that's the complication: what `git checkout` is doing is a subset of what [the `git read-tree` documentation calls a *two tree merge*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_two_tree_merge).  If you follow this link, you'll see that this has 21 separate cases listed (one, case #3, has two sub-cases, and I'm ignoring case #0 which cannot happen, so if you count the sub-cases and case #0 you get 23 different cases).  I won't list them all here, but they kind of boil down to this idea:  **If Git doesn't have to touch the index and work-tree when switching commits, it doesn't.**  That's what keeps your uncommitted changes in place: Git is not *re-applying* anything, it's just not *ripping out* anything either.  It just gently tiptoes around the uncommitted changes.

That, in turn, sort of (but not entirely) explains this radically different behavior, that some—including me—might go so far as to call *evil:*

> This functions in stark contrast to `git checkout commit file` which just blindly discards any uncommitted changes (without any warning) of *`file`* and "forces" the state of *`file`* to that in *`commit`*.

Right, and this is because Git views your command as a request to *replace* the index copy of *`file`* with that from *`commit`*.  The updated index copy is copied out to the work-tree as well.

I would argue (and have in the past) that this should be a *separate Git command*.  It happens to be implemented by the same source code simply because that source code is full of "extract file from commit, write to index and work-tree" code.  But so is `git reset`, and `git reset` *is* a separate command.<sup>1</sup>  So this is at best an excuse of the [Hysterical Raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html) form.

> Surely it could have been made such that `git checkout commit file` attempted to reapply uncommitted changes to *`file`* and failed gracefully if that failed.

That, too, is available in `git checkout`, under the `-m` option ... sort of.  However, it's not on a *per file* basis, but rather on a *whole commit* basis only.  That is, you can `git checkout -m commit`, which merges your work-tree with the target commit (as a three-tree merge), but not `git checkout -m commit file`.  To get that effect, extract the file from the commit, choose a merge base version to extract, and use `git merge-file` on the three files:

```
git show other:file > file.other
git show base:file > file.base
git merge-file file file.base file.other
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Git's `reset` *also* crams too many unrelated bits of functionality into one user-facing command, if you ask me, but you didn't.

> (On a side note, the behavior of `git reset commit` and `git reset file` also leaves room for improvement in consistency...)

OK, maybe you did! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you check out a commit, git does not "reapply" changes.  It leaves modified work tree and index copies unchanged if and only if the checkout would not affect the file - i.e. the version of the file in the commit you're checking out is the same as the version of the file in the pre-checkout HEAD commit.  But if it has to touch a file at all, and the index or working tree copy of that file has modifications, then the checkout aborts.

When you `checkout` a specific path, that path is clobbered without warning because that is the definition and purpose of checking out a specific path.  You say `git checkout -- myfile.txt` specifically because you *want* to revert `myfile.txt`, and in fact that's the command `git status` would recommend using if you want to revert `myfile.txt`.  Keep in mind that for this to be consistent with the "checkout commit" behavior, it *still* wouldn't try to reapply (merge) the local changes; it would just refuse to do the checkout on any modified file.  (And it's fair to say that wouldn't make much sense.)

The seeming inconsistency is one of several symptoms of the unfortunate choice to use the same keyword for two entirely different operations.  While either of those operations could reasonably be named "checkout", it is one of the few decisions I *really* dislike about git that it uses that name for both.